# Gparted Won't start due to a bug

Tags: gparted

I want to extend my home partition size but Gparted won't start. I also tried live boot mode but the error is still there. Is there something wrong with my disk? I really need to add some space to my home folder so that I can run a Virtual Machine on my Ubuntu. If you know any solution to this problem I'd really appreciate your help.

Here is a screen shot of the error.

[image]

Comment: Have you used "Easus partition manager" on this disk in the past?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the current Gparted related to partitions with no space between them. See the discussion in

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1543704

Answer (score 1):

You can try a few things.

First make sure you have the latest install of gparted:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted
```

If the issue remains you can always use the live version of gparted you can [download this here.](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-0.25.0-3-i686.iso)

After downloading burn it to a cd or usb drive and boot the live version of gparted.

Note: This bug is confirmed. Make sure you have the latest release.